# What is the Source of the Assembly Binding Information when the compiler attempts to resolve assembly references?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-assembly

I installed Azure.Core 1.28 into several projects in my Solution and started getting assembly reference errors pointing to the system attempting to resolve to Azure.Core 1.25

I have researched every source and suggestion on SO in effort of resolution for this but nothing I've read and tried appear to work in identifying exactly where this reference to this Azure.Core 1.25 assembly.

I enabled log tracing and it tells me the areas that are being probed but it doesn't provide a clue as to where this specific version is being called.

If I could at least determine where the reference is emanating from I believe I could be more than 1/2 way to resolution. I installed Azure 1.25 as a last effort since that would seem to satisfy the probe but then I still get Minor version conflicts and pretty much end up in the same place.

Where is the initial DisplayName info coming from???

```
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the 
assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.25.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Azure.Core, Version=1.25.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/adm/source/repos/WebApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\adm\source\repos\WebApp\bin
Calling assembly : Azure.Identity, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\adm\source\repos\WebApp\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Azure.Core, Version=1.25.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/app/3ee38c29/99826036/Azure.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/app/3ee38c29/99826036/Azure.Core/Azure.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/adm/source/repos/WebApp/bin/Azure.Core.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

In effort of attempting to identify where the reference is coming from I've

- Performed a full search of my entire system drive
- Ran an uninstall of any instances of Azure.Core from the GAC using an /f switch and received the message that the assembly wasn't present
- Performed an install of the Azure.Core 1.28 version from my packages directory into the GAC and affirmed it there
- Performed a full thorough search of the Solution for any references to Azure.Core 1.25 and found nothing.
- Checked both %windir%\Assembly and %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly and identified the correct Azure.Core 1.28 version in the latter directory (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Azure.Core)
- Searched every app and web configuration file and setting in the Solution
- Checked the Project file references/inclusions

Is there any other way to identify where the reference is coming from aside from what I've already listed?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but have you inspected those three config files that are mentioned in the binding trace?

Comment: Yes, I checked all the config files and running the assembly binding log viewer reports no issue with the assembly. Says binding was successful. I figured if I knew where the pre-bind state information was being pulled from maybe I could trace the problem. Thanks